# Process.run() on local machine during Flutter integration test

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I write some integration tests for my Flutter application and I need to execute some shell commands on my local machine during testing.

I know that I can execute these commands with `Process.run()`, but during the integration tests this command is executed on my android phone instead of my local machine.

Is there any way to run a command on my local machine during my integration test?

Comment: Have you found answer yet?

Comment: No and I think it isn't possible inside tests. But it's possible before all tests are executed which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow with flutter driver it works running processes on your test machine.

In my case it is opening a deep link while running flutter tests. then you get the context.

```
flutter drive \
--driver=test_driver/driver_tests/your_test.dart \
--target=test_driver/your_driver.dart
```

your_driver.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:arriba/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();
  app.main();
}
```

your_test.dart:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

//!! DOES NOT RUN WITHOUT FLUTTER DRIVER MAIN !!
void main() {
  late FlutterDriver driver;

  const String shareLink = 'your_link.html';

  setUpAll(() async {
    driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  });

  tearDownAll(() async {
    await driver.close();
  });

  test(
    'starting deep link test',
    () async {
      driver.waitUntilFirstFrameRasterized();
      await Process.run(
        'adb',
        [
          '-d',
          'shell',
          'am',
          'start',
          '-a android.intent.action.VIEW',
          '-c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE',
          '-d $shareLink',
          'YOUR PACKAGE NAME',
        ],
      ).then((result) {
        stdout.write(result.stdout);
        stderr.write(result.stderr);
      });
    },
    timeout: const Timeout(Duration(seconds: 60)),
  );
}
```